# Task Runner Explorer ASP.NET - Block-scoped declarations not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: asp.net, node.js, visual-studio, webpack

I have been getting this error for days now and I am not sure how to fix it.

When I run the "dev" package in Node Task Runner Explorer it gives this error.

It seems to be something to do with different versions of node and webpack not getting along. the error message, and my packages.json file are below, as is the link to the article I am working through.

[setting-up-a-react-environment-for-aspnet-mvc-44la](https://dev.to/dance2die/setting-up-a-react-environment-for-aspnet-mvc-44la)

**Error Message**

```
C:\DevFolder\MyApplication> cmd.exe /c npm run dev --color=always

asp.net@1.0.0 dev C:\DevFolder\MyApplication
webpack --mode development --watch C:\DevFolder\MyApplication\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:90    let
 notify =   ^^^ SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const,
 function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
     at startup (node.js:141:18)
     at node.js:980:3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! asp.net@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development --watch` npm ERR!
 Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the asp.net@1.0.0 dev
 script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
 likely additional logging output above.
```

**package.json**

```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack",
      "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
      "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
      "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
      "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
      "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
      "webpack": "^4.41.2",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
      "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "^16.12.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
      "npm": "6.12.1",
      "node" : "5.3.0"
    }
  }
```

**Webpack Config**

```
"use strict";

var path = require("path");
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require("webpack-notifier");
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./Scripts/ApplicationReact/ApplicationReact.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./Scripts/"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [new WebpackNotifierPlugin(), new BrowserSyncPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config file

Comment: Hi Tony, I have updated the question. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Try to remove `"use strict";`

Comment: I tried taking out the "use strict" and it is still throwing the same error. I also just tried making lots of syntax errors and corrupting the file and it has made no effect, I think that node task runner is not picking up the config file at all. the file is called "webpack.config.js"

Comment: Would you mind share your code on github ? Really hard for me to debug without running the code

Comment: I will have a look into it, the new javascript code is sat on top of a huge sprawling fifteen year old pile of asp.net web site project chaos. I am investigating trying to fit react onto the top of it as part of a staged migration. I will try to create a cut down test project. I will be at this a couple of days i think. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

Don't install the Node.js nuget package, it breaks your project and it will remain broken after you have removed it. Just let the general installation of node do the work.

### Detail

When in any other directory, if I did "node -v" in the command line and it would return version 12.13.1

When in my project folder if I did "node -v" it would return 5.3.0

When I removed the Node.js nuget package I thought it would default to the system version but instead it just said "cannot find the file or command specified" (or something along those lines).

I had copied the whole of our software to another folder for the purposes of this exercise. I just branched to another folder and this time the "node -v" was coming back with 12.13.1

I carried on with the exercise and the error did not appear. I am not sure how to fix it once you get into this state.

### Better answers?

This isn't a great answer and I won't mark it as the answer. If anyone can provide a plausible explanation for what is going on here, and a way to cure your project from the nuget node lurgy, I will mark it as the answer.